# PackagesNotFoundError When Trying to Install intel_extension_for_pytorch

Tags: intel-oneapi, intel-pytorch, intel-ai-analytics

I am trying to conda install intel_extension_for_pytorch but I keep getting the following error in the command line:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- intel_extension_for_pytorch

this is the command that I am using

`conda install intel_extension_for_pytorch`

edit:

System Info:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2006]
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz, 2995 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Could you please provide your system information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Intel Extension for PyTorch is only supported by Linux OS. Try on a recent Linux version, it should work there.

Check out the docs for more info: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/extension-for-pytorch.html

Comment: Yes, this worked! Do you know if Windows will be supported soon? For the time being, I guess I could use an AWS Linux machine.